# SQLITE INSERT gives " Parameter count mismatch" in Qt 5.0.2 while working in Qt 5.10.1

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, qt5

code:

```
// testing insert in qt5.0.2
q->prepare(tr("INSERT INTO STUDENTS (MARKS_SSC, TOTAL_SSC,"
              " PERC_SSC, BOARD_SSC, SCHOOL_SSC,"
              " MONTH_YEAR_SSC)"
              " VALUES(:marks_ssc, :total_ssc,"
              " :perc_ssc, :board_ssc,"
              " :school_ssc, :month_year_ssc)"));
q->bindValue(":marks_ssc", stud->marks_ssc);
q->bindValue(":total_ssc", stud->total_ssc);
q->bindValue(":perc_ssc", stud->perc_ssc);
q->bindValue(":board_ssc", stud->board_ssc);
q->bindValue(":school_ssc", stud->school_ssc);
q->bindValue(":month_year_ssc", stud->month_year_ssc);

qDebug() << q->executedQuery();

if(q->exec()){
    qDebug() << "New record entry successfull!";
}else{
    qDebug() << "New record entry failed!!!";
    qDebug() << q->lastError().text();
}
```

Output:

> "INSERT INTO STUDENTS (MARKS_SSC, TOTAL_SSC, PERC_SSC, BOARD_SSC, SCHOOL_SSC, MONTH_YEAR_SSC) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
>
> New record entry failed!!!
> " Parameter count mismatch"

Comment: What does that `tr()` do?

Comment: @LukStorms `tr()` stands for "translate" (as in, translate to another language) and is used for localization - typically for string literals that appear in the UI. It makes absolutely no sense to apply it to the text of a SQL query. That said, when running in English locale it's a no-op, and seems unlikely to be the immediate cause of the problem.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, found something like that online, and that got me wondering why one would translate a query.  But since I don't know Qt couldn't be sure about it. I can only wonder how that query would look in my native non-english language.

Comment: Removing `tr()` didn't work